# Failed to load PDF document once sent by nodemailer attachments

Tags: node.js, base64, attachment, nodemailer

The email and attachment is successfully sent but the attachment failed to be opened/read!

Here is the code :

```
 let str = Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64')

console.log("str",str) //HelloWorlQ==

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'test5@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: "test@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject:"test", // Subject line
    attachments:[
        {   // encoded string as an attachment
        filename: 'text1.pdf',
        content: str,
        encoding: 'base64',
        contentType: "application/pdf"
    }
    ],
  });
```

Any clue please ?

Comment: reading a file is asynchronous, use async await

Comment: A Base64-encoded string of "Hello World" isn't a valid PDF.

Comment: @robertklep So what's  the format valid for PDF ?

Comment: You need to create an actual PDF file using a PDF-generator like [`pdfjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs).